# PL/SQL Package using authid current_user

Tags: oracle, plsql

Schema A owns two packages ,pkg1 has current_user invoker rights and pkg2 has definer rights.
pkg1 procedures calls second package procedures.

Now i have created public synonyms for these 2 packages and given grants to Schema B and C.

B able to execute one of the procedure only if both packages have authid current_user rights where as C is failing with insufficient privileges if i don't use definer rights for both and viceversa.

I was trying to give direct grants on the objects,and DBA role to B schema but its not working. Is there anyway i can run these packages from both users.

I am not able to attach the code

From B: I m trying to run this procedure

```
exec pkg1.empty_clobs('Schema','Table',13); --which calls pkg2 procedure
```

From C:

exec pkg1.disable_constraint('schema','off','table','table_constrnt'); ----which calls pkg2 procedure internally

Thanks.

Comment: Without code (it doesn't have to be the actual code you're using just something that reproduces the issue), it's probably impossible to answer.  Assuming that A has privileges to do whatever the two procedures do, it doesn't make sense that one caller would get an error if both procedures are definer's rights stored procedures.  If what you are describing is correct, there is something else that is missing from your description that is rather important.

Comment: in pkg1 you probably work with db objects the user B and C have no privileges to, grant missing privileges...